# Kepler's equation and eccentric anomaly

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements, eccentric-orbit

From the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly) about eccentric anomaly follows:

$$\cos E = \frac{x}{a}$$
$$\sin E = \frac{y}{b}$$

where E - eccentric anomaly, a - semi-major axis, b - semi-minor axis, P = P(x,y) a point on elleptic orbit. So if you know an E, you can find a position on an orbit:

$$x = a \cos E$$
$$y = b \sin E$$

However, from [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) on Kepler's eqution follows:

$$x = a (\cos E - e)$$
$$y = b \sin E$$

Please, help to understand why these formaluae differ? I expect them to be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both formulae are correct. The discrepancy is because the formula from the eccentric anomaly article uses the *centre* of the ellipse as the origin, but the formula from the Kepler's equation article uses a *focus* of the ellipse (i.e, the central gravitating body, eg the Sun) as the origin. Note that $c = ae$ is the distance from the ellipse centre to a focus

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear. Can't upvote the answer since I don't have enough rep.

Comment: @Jonas I've upvoted both question and answer, we'll get you there soon!

Comment: See my answer [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43350/16685) for a diagram showing the eccentric anomaly.